# Gradient of a radial function at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $C_{c,r}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$ denote the smooth functions $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $f(x) = f(|x| e_1)$. My lecture notes say that $\nabla f(0) = 0$. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypotheses imply that $f(x)=f(-x).$ Thus

$$D_k f(x)= D_k f(-x)(-1).$$

If $x=0,$ then we have $D_k f(0)= -D_k f(0).$ Thus $D_k f(0)=0.$ This is true for every $k,$ giving the result.

Comment: Can I just use the following definition of the gradient:
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x + h ) - f(x - h) - 2\nabla f(x) \cdot h|}{||h||} = 0$?

Comment: I edited my answer to a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $f'(0)$ does not exist.

In some special cases where $f'(0)$ exists, [for example $f(\vec{x})=0$], the derivative can only be $0$.

Comment: The OP is assuming $f$ is infinitely differentiable.